# Op-amp not amplifying noise correctly - saturating

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, saturation

I'm trying to produce white noise using an NPN transistor and amplify it using an op-amp. But the signal is being saturated as you see. I'd like to know how to change this setup to make it work without being saturated.

The first transistor produces the white noise, which is further pre-amplified by the second transistor. The capacitor cuts DC, but the signal is already saturated there as you see in the first Picoscope image. In the second image you see the output at the end of the op-amp, which is 1) not amplified with the expected gain 2) and it's being saturated aswell (probably because the original signal is saturated).

First image: V1
Second image: V2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzbrpX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the biasing for both Q2 and OA1? Both of these look suspect to me.

Answer (score 1):

From the NE5532 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532a.pdf), we have this:

[image]

With a +/-15V supply the inputs must be in the range +/-12V. We can infer from
that the behavior with a +16V/0V supply.

You've got the inputs at ~Vcc- when they should be at least 3V higher.

You can add a negative supply or rework the biasing.

Comment: I added some bias through a voltage divider from VCC to GND. Put 1K as the first resistor and 4.9K as second resistor. Now I'm getting the noise at 12V, but now I just see an almost straight line, so the op amp is not amplifying